# How to pass array values to TFDConnection.ExecSQLScalar?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, delphi, firedac

I would like to pass the array as a parameter of the TFDConnection.ExecSQLScalar method to a PostgreSQL database function. I've been researching how to call the function using the ftArray field type, but I haven't found any.

```
create or replace function get_my_answer(_my_args integer[]) returns boolean
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
  return true;
end;
$$;
```

In Delphi my function is like this:

```pascal
function GetDbAnswer(_myargs: array of integer): Boolean;
begin
//  Result:= MyConnection.ExecSQLScalar('select get_my_answer(:_myargs)', [_myargs], [ftArray]);
//  Error  [FireDAC][Stan]-19. Data type conversion is not supported.

//  Result:= MyConnection.ExecSQLScalar('select get_my_answer(:_myargs)', [_myargs], [ftUnknown]);
//  Error  [FireDAC][Phys][PG]-335. Parameter [MY_ARGS] data type is unknown. Hint: specify TFDParam.DataType or assign TFDParam value before Prepare/Execute call.
end;
```

Is it possible to pass an array directly into the function or will I have to convert the values to another type?

Comment: Try [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.ArrayType) with type `atTable`.

Comment: @Olivier, thank you for your answer, but, ExecSQLScalar don't accept TFDParam as parameter. Can you detail how can i use it in this case? [This example](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.3.3Demos/blob/master/Object%20Pascal/Database/FireDAC/Samples/DBMS%20Specific/PostgreSQL/Arrays/fMain.pas) uses TFDQuery

Comment: Just don't use `ExecSQLScalar()`, that's all.